# How to take professional photo's

Tags: digital, product-photography, learning

i want to learn to make professional photo's,  but i dont know where to begin, and where to get my inspiration from. Like when and where it is best to photograph. 
Any idea's?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use the online platform http://www.lynda.com. Try the 14 day trial and explore the different photography courses that offers. Additionally, you can find plenty of books on Amazon. There is a great series called "From snapshots to great shots". You will learn a lot and also get some inspiration from the photographs in the books. All of them have also small assignments at the end of each chapter that make you practise on the things you just read.

Comment: Thank you verry much for the advice. I am sure i will learn of the advice